# Redirect with .htaccess without changing URL in address bar

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This question has been asked before, but I'm not getting the expected results following the solutions in there.

I simply need to make a redirect with .htaccess without changing the URL in the address bar.
That is,

```
www.mydomain.com/en-uk
```

should redirect to

```
www.mydomain.com/en
```

but the address bar should still display

```
www.mydomain.com/en-uk
```

I've tried a few things but no matter how I do it the URL changes to the redirected path. As of now, I have this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /en-uk/(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/en//$1/
```

Also, it should be noted that my site uses WordPress. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to look into `RewriteRule`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks, I'll check the link; although I've already tried quite a few combinations of RewriteRules to no avail so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en-uk(/.*)?$ /en$1 [L]
```

Comment: Well, it does the redirect part just fine, but the URL changes in the address bar. Maybe there's a conflict with my WP settings?

Comment: @mustieles maybe, the rule above does not redirect the browser unless there's an `R` flag. If you're using wordpress, you should probably just use wordpress's rewrite mod

Comment: The problem with WordPress' built-in rewrite mod is that, again, the URL changes to the new path in the address bar; just what I'm trying to avoid. Thanks anyway!